# How to create a floating graph with time on y axis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, graph, count

I need to create one graph with its x-axis should be

> 0,1,2..10

y-axis should be out current time + next 10 times with an interval of five minites.
like this

> array = [1.45, 1.50, 1.55, 2.00, 2.05, 2.10, 2.15, 2.20, 2.25, 2.30];

Any body can help me with some sample codes.

Thanks

Comment: What is "out current time"?  How does it relate to the sequence you've shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the charts libraries like [`flot`](http://code.google.com/p/flot/). Or if you have to write your own code I'd suggest looking at [`Canvas`](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_canvas.asp).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy javascript graphing solution check out [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You should also have a look at [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/chart/). Look at the [line graph examples](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html).